# Python transformar json

Tags: python, json

Llevo varios dias con un problema que me esta matando poco a poco.

El problema que tengo es que necesito convertir(o transformar) un json teniendo en cuenta que se agrupa por una propiedad(OPERATOR).

Es decir si yo tengo el siguiente JSON.

```
[{
        "HEADER_DATE": "2019-03-01",
        "IMPORTE": 24537.377,
        "OP": "OP1",
        "OPERATOR": "OPERADOR1"
    },
    {
        "HEADER_DATE": "2018-12-01",
        "IMPORTE": 48831.8088,
        "OP": "OP1",
        "OPERATOR": "OPERADOR1"
    },
    {
        "HEADER_DATE": "2018-05-01",
        "IMPORTE": 536801.9383,
        "OP": "OP2",
        "OPERATOR": "OPERADOR2"
    },
    {
        "HEADER_DATE": "2018-05-01",
        "IMPORTE": 4283.5844,
        "OP": "OP3",
        "OPERATOR": "OPERADOR3"
    },
    {
        "HEADER_DATE": "2018-12-01",
        "IMPORTE": 4254.775,
        "OP": "OP3",
        "OPERATOR": "OPERADOR3"
    }
]
```

El resultado esperado tendria que ser algo asi.

```
[{
        "2019-03-01": 24537.377,
        "2018-12-01": 48831.8088,
        "OP": "OP1",
        "OPERATOR": "OPERADOR1"
    }, {
        "2018-05-01": 536801.9383,
        "OP": "OP2",
        "OPERATOR": "OPERADOR2"
    },
    {
        "2018-05-01": 4283.5844,
        "2018-12-01": 4254.775,
        "OP": "OP2",
        "OPERATOR": "OPERADOR3"
    }
]
```

Es decir, la clave **HEADER_DATE** pasaria a ser la key del nuevo json y su valor seria el valor de la clave **IMPORTE** agrupado por el operador.

Aquí va el codigo que estuve haciendo.

```
class Pivot(object):


    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data


    def pivot(self, as_key=None, as_value=None):
        item = []
        last_operator = None
        ob = {}
        for x in self.data:
            if as_key in x and as_value in x:
                try:
                    ob[x[as_key]] = float(x[as_value])
                except:
                    ob[x[as_key]] = x[as_value]

                for key,val in x.items():
                    if x[as_key]  in ob and key != as_key and key != as_value:
                        ob[key] = val
                if last_operator != x["OPERATOR"]:
                    item.append(ob)
                    last_operator = x["OPERATOR"]

        return item
```

> Ignora los parametros del metodo pivot

Gracias por cualquier ayuda y espero haberme explicado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a intentar explicar porqué falla tu aproximación y en dar soluciones basadas en tu código. Formas de hacerlo existen muchas, incluso Pandas podría ser una opción.

El primer error en tu código está en que terminas creando una lista en las que **todos sus items son el mismo diccionario**, dado que `ob` es siempre la misma instancia. Esto lo puedes solucionar simplemente moviendo tu último condicional situándolo justo antes del `try` y redefiniendo `ob` antes de añadirlo a la lista `item`. De esta forma, cada vez que el valor de `OPERATOR` cambie se crea un nuevo diccionario.

Esto es suficiente si **tienes la total seguridad de tener la lista con los diccionarios ordenados en función del valor de `OPERATOR`**. En caso contrario siempre puedes ordenarla usando `sorted`/`list.sort` y su argumento `key`:

```
import operator

class Pivot(object):


    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data


    def pivot(self, as_key=None, as_value=None):
        item = []
        last_operator = None
        for x in sorted(self.data, key=operator.itemgetter("OPERATOR")):
            if as_key in x and as_value in x:
                if last_operator is None or last_operator != x["OPERATOR"]:
                    ob = {}
                    item.append(ob)
                    last_operator = x["OPERATOR"]
                try:
                    ob[x[as_key]] = float(x[as_value])
                except:
                    ob[x[as_key]] = x[as_value]

                for key,val in x.items():
                    if x[as_key]  in ob and key != as_key and key != as_value:
                        ob[key] = val

        return item
```

Esto nos crea:

```
[{'2019-03-01': 24537.377,
  'OP': 'OP1',
  'OPERATOR': 'OPERADOR1',
  '2018-12-01': 48831.8088},

 {'2018-05-01': 536801.9383,
  'OP': 'OP2',
  'OPERATOR': 'OPERADOR2'},

 {'2018-05-01': 4283.5844,
  'OP': 'OP3',
  'OPERATOR': 'OPERADOR3',
  '2018-12-01': 4254.775}]
```

Existen muchas opciones de hacer lo mismo, sin necesidad de ordenar puedes recurrir a un diccionario auxiliar que pueda ir almacenando como clave cada valor distinto de `OPERATOR` y como valor el diccionario de salida para ese `OPERATOR`:

```
from collections import  defaultdict



class Pivot(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data


    def pivot(self, group_by, as_key=None, as_value=None):

        temp = defaultdict(dict)
        for x in self.data:
            group_by_val = x.get(group_by)
            as_key_val = x.get(as_key)
            as_value_val = x.get(as_value)

            if group_by_val is not None and as_key_val is not None and as_value_val is not None:
                for key, value in x.items():
                    if key != as_key and key != as_value:
                        temp[group_by_val][key] = value
                try:
                    temp[group_by_val][as_key_val] = float(as_value_val)
                except ValueError:
                    temp[group_by_val][as_key_val] = x[as_value_val]


        return list(temp.values())



json = [{
        "HEADER_DATE": "2019-03-01",
        "IMPORTE": 24537.377,
        "OP": "OP1",
        "OPERATOR": "OPERADOR1"
    },
    {
        "HEADER_DATE": "2018-05-01",
        "IMPORTE": 536801.9383,
        "OP": "OP2",
        "OPERATOR": "OPERADOR2"
    },
    {
        "HEADER_DATE": "2018-12-01",
        "IMPORTE": 48831.8088,
        "OP": "OP1",
        "OPERATOR": "OPERADOR1"
    },
    {
        "HEADER_DATE": "2018-05-01",
        "IMPORTE": 4283.5844,
        "OP": "OP3",
        "OPERATOR": "OPERADOR3"
    },
    {
        "HEADER_DATE": "2018-12-01",
        "IMPORTE": 4254.775,
        "OP": "OP3",
        "OPERATOR": "OPERADOR3"
    }] 

pivot = Pivot(json)
pivot_json = pivot.pivot("OPERATOR", "HEADER_DATE", "IMPORTE")
```

La salida es:

```
[{'OP': 'OP1',
  'OPERATOR': 'OPERADOR1',
  '2019-03-01': 24537.377,
  '2018-12-01': 48831.8088},

 {'OP': 'OP2',
  'OPERATOR': 'OPERADOR2',
  '2018-05-01': 536801.9383},

 {'OP': 'OP3',
  'OPERATOR': 'OPERADOR3',
  '2018-05-01': 4283.5844,
  '2018-12-01': 4254.775}]
```

No le he dado mucha importancia al orden de los itens en los diccionarios y no se si es importante para ti, de cualquier forma esto solo tendría relevancia en Python >= 3.6 dónde los diccionarios mantiene el orden de inserción.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta y me funciona perfecto, me gusta mucho tu solucion ya que es más dinamica(gracias a los parametros). De nuevo gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Vamos con una solución que hace uso de partes poco usadas (y quizás poco conocidas) de la biblioteca estándar Python.

Imagina que tuviéramos una lista de diccionarios, en la que todos los diccionarios que forman la lista tienen ya el mismo valor en el campo "OPERATOR". Podríamos crear un diccionario "resumen" de esa lista con la siguiente función:

```
def create_dict(datos):
  d = dict((dato["HEADER_DATE"], dato["IMPORTE"]) for dato in datos)     
  d.update(OPERATOR=datos[0]["OPERATOR"], OP=datos[0]["OP"])
  return d
```

La parte un poco "rara" aquí es la línea que inicializa `d`, que lo hace con el constructor `dict` al que se le pasan una serie de tuplas. Este constructor usa el primer elemento de cada tupla como clave y el segundo elemento como valor. Así que le paso una serie de tuplas que tienen las fechas como primer elemento y los importes como segundo elemento. Uso una expresión generadora para iterar por todos los diccionarios de la lista `datos` que recibí como parámetro. Después (con `.update()`) le añado el los campos "OPERATOR" y "OP", sacándolos del primer elemento de la lista pues se entiende que es igual en todos los elementos.

Ahora bien, en tu lista no todos los diccionarios tienen el mismo "OPERATOR", por lo que la función anterior no es directamente utilizable. Tenemos que romper tu lista original en varias sub-listas, de modo que cada sub-lista sí tenga el mismo "OPERATOR", y así pasaríamos cada sub-lista a la función anterior para obtener un solo diccionario que resume la sub-lista.

Para romper la lista original en sublistas, Python proporciona `itertools.groupby()` que itera por la lista que reciba como parámetro, aplicando a cada elemento de la lista una función `key` que también le tienes que pasar como parámetro, y agrupando todos los elementos de la lista que produzcan el mismo resultado al evaluar sobre ellos la función `key`.

En nuestro caso la función `key` consistirá en extraer el campo "OPERATOR" de cada elemento de la lista. Para esto podemos hacer uso del método `operators.itemgetter`.

Juntando estas piezas podríamos hacer lo siguiente:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operators import itemgetter

grupos = groupby(tu_lista_inicial, key=itemgetter("OPERATOR"))
```

Eso deja en `grupos` un iterable. Cada vez que iteres por él te devolverá una pareja (una tupla) cuyo primer elemento es el valor de la "clave" según la cual ha agrupado (en nuestro caso, el valor del "OPERATOR") y cuyo segundo elemento es otro iterable que nos da los elementos que han sido agrupados (o sea, las sub-listas que buscábamos en las que todos los elementos tienen el mismo "OPERATOR").

En base a este resultado ya bastaría con hacer:

```
final = [ create_dict(list(datos)) for _, datos in grupos ]
```

Un último detalle es que `groupby()` necesita que la lista de entrada esté ordenada por la misma `key` por la que va a agrupar, ya que en el fondo lo que hace es dar por terminado un grupo cada vez que ve que la "clave" cambia.

En tu caso parece que efectivamente la lista de entrada está ordenada de ese modo, pues los dos primeros diccionarios son del "OPERADOR1", el siguiente es del "OPERADOR2" y los dos siguientes del "OPERADOR3". Pero en un caso más general deberías ordenarla de antemano, con algo como:

```
lista_ordenada = sorted(tu_lista_original, key=itemgetter("OPERATOR"))
```

### Juntando todo

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

def create_dict(datos):
  d = dict((dato["HEADER_DATE"], dato["IMPORTE"]) for dato in datos)     
  d.update(OPERATOR=datos[0]["OPERATOR"], OP=datos[0]["OP"])
  return d

lista_ordenada = sorted(tu_lista_original, key=itemgetter("OPERATOR"))
grupos = groupby(lista_ordenada, key=itemgetter("OPERATOR"))
final = [ create_dict(list(datos)) for _, datos in grupos ]
```

Y produce el resultado:

```
[{'2018-12-01': 48831.8088,
  '2019-03-01': 24537.377,
  'OP': 'OP1',
  'OPERATOR': 'OPERADOR1'},
 {'2018-05-01': 536801.9383,
  'OP': 'OP2', 
  'OPERATOR': 'OPERADOR2'},
 {'2018-05-01': 4283.5844,
  '2018-12-01': 4254.775,
  'OP': 'OP3',
  'OPERATOR': 'OPERADOR3'}]
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu solución, funciona perfectamente, pero la respuesta de @FJSevilla se ajusta más a lo que estoy buscando. A parte me has resuelto un par de dudas en general. Gracias de nuevo.

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

**ejemplo:**

```
json = [{
        "HEADER_DATE": "2019-03-01",
        "IMPORTE": 24537.377,
        "OP": "OP1",
        "OPERATOR": "OPERADOR1"
    },
    {
        "HEADER_DATE": "2018-12-01",
        "IMPORTE": 48831.8088,
        "OP": "OP1",
        "OPERATOR": "OPERADOR1"
    },
    {
        "HEADER_DATE": "2018-05-01",
        "IMPORTE": 536801.9383,
        "OP": "OP2",
        "OPERATOR": "OPERADOR2"
    },
    {
        "HEADER_DATE": "2018-05-01",
        "IMPORTE": 4283.5844,
        "OP": "OP3",
        "OPERATOR": "OPERADOR3"
    },
    {
        "HEADER_DATE": "2018-12-01",
        "IMPORTE": 4254.775,
        "OP": "OP3",
        "OPERATOR": "OPERADOR3"
    }]

# almacenara el nuevo json
result = []
# almacenara los operator
operator = []

# recorremos el json
for i in json:
    # validamos que exita operator en operator
    if i["OPERATOR"] in operator:
        # recorremos result
        for x in result:
            # buscamos el operator
            if i["OPERATOR"] == x["OPERATOR"]:
                # y le agremaos la fecha y el importe
                x.update({i["HEADER_DATE"] :  i["IMPORTE"]})

    # en caso de no existir
    else:
        # agregamos el operator a operator
        operator.append(i["OPERATOR"])
        # creamos el nuevo json y los agregamos al resultado
        result.append({i["HEADER_DATE"] :  i["IMPORTE"],
                        "OP": i["OP"],
                        "OPERATOR": i["OPERATOR"]
                    })

print(result)
```

**el resultado seria:**

```
[{'2018-12-01': 48831.8088,
  '2019-03-01': 24537.377,
  'OP': 'OP1',
  'OPERATOR': 'OPERADOR1'},
 {'2018-05-01': 536801.9383, 'OP': 'OP2', 'OPERATOR': 'OPERADOR2'},
 {'2018-05-01': 4283.5844,
  '2018-12-01': 4254.775,
  'OP': 'OP3',
  'OPERATOR': 'OPERADOR3'}]
```

Comment: Agradezco tu ayuda, pero no es lo que realmente necesito ya que en tu ejemplo solo te estas quedado con uno de ellos(El primero). Gracias igualmente.

Comment: sorry lei mal ya corregi.